# How do I put a button on a Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

So I can do a button in a simple window but not on a Canvas.

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
def function():
    print('Hello World')

tk_button = Button(window, text = 'Click me!', command = function)
```

I want to position the button on a tkinter Canvas and have graphics around it, not just the bare window with the button.

Comment: Read up on the `create_window` method of the canvas.

Comment: I tried that, but the buttons are not clickable, only works after a Ctrl-C keyboard-interrupt which then prevents the function it's linked to from working.

Comment: Post what you have tried, otherwise no one can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the create_window function on a canvas to put a frame on it, then use that frame to pack other widgets normally.

```
import tkinter as tk

mw = tk.Tk()


canvas = tk.Canvas(mw, bg='grey75')
canvas.pack()


frame = tk.Frame(canvas, width=50, height=5)
canvas.create_window((1,1), window=frame, anchor='nw')

button = tk.Button(frame, text='Hello World')
button.pack()

mw.mainloop()
```